# Can a C program get the character mouse is hovering over in Windows Console?

Tags: c, get, console, character, mouseover

There have been questions and answers regarding to Mouse Input but Mouse Input doesn't seem to be solving this problem.

Lets say the word "chair" is printed on the Console. Is there a way to get which character ('c','h','a','i','r' or none) mouse hovers over?

I don't really need the function to continuously update itself, I need to learn the character only once (like when the user presses a button).

Comment: I suggest you explore the [Windows console API functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` function of the console API will get you as close as you can get to what you want (I think) but with extra steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo

As you can see, it returns a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure which not only contains the position of the cursor (`dwCursorPosition`), but also character positions (`wAttributes`).

The downside is this can only be done in a screen buffer, where the user can move the cursor the same way he would interact with the cmd on writing a command (with left-right arrows, on click, etc...).

So yeah, I don't think you could detect a mouse over but with a screen buffer you can have the user click on the characters or navigate through them and be aware of this position.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to [track mouse movement with `ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) which will give you console screen buffer coordinates of the mouse pointer and then get the character with `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`, something like:

```
INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
DWORD cNumRead;
int i;
COORD coord;

while (1)
{
    ReadConsoleInput(
        GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),      // input buffer handle 
        irInBuf,     // buffer to read into 
        128,         // size of read buffer 
        &cNumRead);
    for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
    {
        if (irInBuf[i].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT)
        {
            MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer = irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent;
            switch (mer.dwEventFlags)
            {
            case 0:

                if (mer.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
                {
                    TCHAR c[2] = { '\0' };
                    DWORD cnum;
                    ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(
                        GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                        c,
                        1,
                        coord,
                        &cnum
                        );
                    if (cnum == 1) MessageBox(NULL, c, NULL, 0);
                }
                break;
            case MOUSE_MOVED:
                //printf("mouse moved\n");
                coord.X = mer.dwMousePosition.X;
                coord.Y = mer.dwMousePosition.Y;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (irInBuf[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT)
        {
            KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker = irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent;
            if (ker.bKeyDown)
            {
                DWORD written;
                WriteConsole(
                    GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                    &ker.uChar,
                    1,
                    &written,
                    NULL
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```